# server.key.der OR server.crt.der of same size

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, der

Is this possible to creat openssl certificate  (server.key.der OR server.crt.der) of same size .. 1024 or 2048 or any fixed size ?
I fond that, it changes the size everytime when ever I creat the cerificates and then I have to change the buffr size. Is there any parameter from where i can fix the size of certificates .

Answer (score 1):

Certificates contain a variable amount of data (such as the common name). Furthermore, ASN.1 is a variable length encoding ([smaller numbers requires less space than larger numbers](https://play.golang.org/p/qwUvMhDfFwu), for instance).

So no, you can neither reliably predict nor control the size of a signed certificate or its key. It should be trivial to define a sane upper bound on the size, though.

Comment: but is it possible if i convert from pem to der formate i can have fix size.

Comment: @embbo, no. PEM is basically just the base64 encoding of the DER data, and the DER data is encoding the ASN.1 structure, and that structure contains variable length data (like the subject). So certificates are fundamentally variable in length.